# i tried to upload a file to upload folder but getting failure message

Tags: php

my directory is looks like this
->source files
   --css
   --upload
   add_file.php
   upload.php

my code is as follows

upload.php

```
 <form role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="add_file.php">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="filecaption">
                        Caption :
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" name="f_caption" class="form-control"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Choose a File">
                        Caption :
                    </label>
                    <input type="file" name="uploaded_file" class="form-control"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">

                    <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload" class="form-control btn btn-warning"/>
                </div>
            </form>
```

add_file.php

```
<?php



if(isset($_FILES['uploaded_file']))
{    
    $f_name= $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'];
    $temp_name= $_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'];

if(!$temp_name)
{
    die("no file uploaded..please try again");
}
else
{
    $path = "upload/" . $f_name;
   if( move_uploaded_file($f_name, $path))
   {
       echo "success";
   }
   else
   {
       echo "failure";
   }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi to you, the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is from the add.php.

Try this

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['uploaded_file'])) {

$f_name= $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'];
$temp_name= $_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'];

if(!$temp_name)
{
    die("no file uploaded..please try again");
}
else
{
    $path = "upload/" . $f_name;
   if( move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $path))
   {
       echo "success";
   }
   else
   {
       echo "failure";
   }
}
}
```

?>

The problem is that you were moving from the f_name instead of the temp_location.

Comment: thx a lot man @Gideon Appoh ..it works..but i just wanted to send the file name to database and file will be stored in uploads folder..how can i achieve that?..

Comment: There are many ways to do it, which will depend on you. You can choose to store only the filename in the database (like mypic.jpg) and when you what to retrieve it you add your path (like `'photos/'.$row['image']`). Provided you have queried you database and stored results as row and the path is in mypic.jpg. Or you can choose to store the whole path in the database (like `'uploads/mypic.jpg'`). All this must be inserted in the database using SQL. I hope you are okay.

Comment: yes i understood and i tried..it works..now i retrieve all documents name and showed in page.but when the user click tht document it should get downlloaded..here is my code